# Connection timeout from Kubernetes to MongoDB droplet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a NodeJS application deployed in a Kubernetes cluster at DigitalOcean. I have a VM (droplet) that hosts a MongoDB instance that is used by the NodeJS application. Both the cluster and the DB droplet are part of the default VPC.

My application running in DigitalOcean K8s is unable to establish a connection to the VM using the VM's public or private IP addresses. However, deploying the app to other K8s clusters outside DigitalOcean works without an issue, provided I whitelist the IP addresses.

I have searched exhaustively and tried the following solutions without success:

- Opened MongoDB port (27017) to the public (all IPs)
- Setup an external name service with an endpoint and tried to use internal DNS names
- Used NMAP within the pods and confirmed the port is open
- Setup Nginx on the DB droplet and successfully curled from the pod

This is the block of code responsible for establishing a connection to MongoDB which works perfectly when connecting from outside the DigitalOcean environment.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://159.65.xxx.xxx:27017/enomy');
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("User Connected to Database");
});
```

I've been struggling with this for days, so any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how exactly did you set up the cluster? Could you provide reproduction steps?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Kubernetes version 1.21. The cluster was created through the DigitalOcean console.